# Flutter Test - Check widgets after first setState

Tags: flutter, widget-test-flutter

I have an action taken on a button click. The method looks like

```
void _buttonAction() async {

   setState(() {
     _loading = true;
   });

   // Api call takes place here

   setState(() {
      _loading = false;
   });
}
```

In my widget test, after the first `setState` I want to check whether my loading widget is displayed, but calling pump seems to progress through both the `setState` so when I try to check for the loading widget it fails. If I comment out the second `setState` then it is able to find the loading widget. How can I properly test this scenario? Here is my test code

```
testWidgets("Loading", (widgetTester) async {
   final Api api = MockApi();
   await widgetTester.pumpWidget(
     MyWidget()
   );


   await widgetTester.tap(find.byType(TextButton));
   await widgetTester.pump();

   expect(find.byType(Loading), findsOneWidget);
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can follow these steps. Add your all setState method to `apiCallingMethod` and check one by one. Here I'm using `provider`, you can use `setState` also.
[image]